# undirectional one to one mapping with forein key in supplementary table?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables with one to one relationship b/w student and address table

```
Student
 student_id
 name

Address
  address_id
  student_id(foreign key to student_id  in student table)
  ...
```

Here is the relevant entity section

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Address address;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
    private long id;

    private long student_id;

}
```

I want to keep the foreign key i.e. `student_id(foreign key to id in student table)` under address table as shown in table structure at top but
want to keep the undirectional association of `private Address address` under student entity. I am not sure how to achieve it ?

**what I tried is this**

@Entity
    @Table(name = "STUDENT")
    public class Student {

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy ="student_id")
    private Address address;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
    private long id;

        @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="student_id")
    private long student_id;

}
```

But it gives below exception

```
@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on Address.student_id references an unknown entity: int
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1580)
    at
```

It works as soon as I make association bidirectional with

`private Student student_id` instead of `private long student_id`

So in a way Hibernate forcing me to make association bidirectional when foreign key exist in supplementary table(in this case address table)